# Transact-SQL DEFAULT keyword deprecated? Why?

Tags: t-sql, deprecated, default-parameters

In MSDN article
[Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)
there is a statement on deprecation of `DEFAULT` keyword ([among the others](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx#Anchor_1)).

Quoted from the table:

> **Category:** Transact-SQL
>
> **Deprecated feature:** Use of DEFAULT keyword as default value.
>
> **Replacement:** Do not use the word DEFAULT as a default value.
>
> **Feature name:** DEFAULT keyword as a default value.
>
> **Feature ID:** 187.

What is the logic behind this change? I find nothing wrong with

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFirstIdByCode(@Code nvarchar(20), @ExcludeThisId int)
```

and in most cases, where I don't use 2nd parameter, call it like

```
IF dbo.GetFirstIdByCode(@Id, DEFAULT) = 0 --- etc...
```

Of course, I can replace `DEFAULT` with NULL at every call of the function. To me, this looks like anything but a progress. Why is this planned?

How should I adjust my coding style preparing for this?

Answer (score 2):

The wording was incorrect:Erland raised a connect item for this..please see this [connect for more details](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/293052/incorrect-depreaction-use-of-default-keyword-as-default-value)..

**Pasting relevant items from connect item:**

Depreceated feature is ..

> using the word DEFAULT as the DEFAULT value.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(Col1 int PRIMARY KEY,
Status varchar(10) DEFAULT 'DEFAULT' )
or
CREATE DEFAULT phonedflt AS 'DEFAULT'
```

Comment: @MrLister:I *think* this was on track to deprecate from 2007 and you found it again on 2016 documentation deprecated features list

Comment: The title complained about in the connect item there is indeed the same as that here `"Use of DEFAULT keyword as default value."` - So looks like they never bothered making the documentation any clearer. Here it is on the 2008 deprecated features list too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.100).aspx